# Rolling median for a large dataset - python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, median

I have a huge file with 200K lines, I need to find out the rolling median by counting distinct words in each line.

I have used numpy to calculate median as below

```
   a = np.array([])
   np.insert(a, 0, len(unique_word_list_by_line))
   median = np.median(a)
```

I feel that this is not efficient as numpy creates a new array everytime i insert an element. Is there a way to insert an element into a numpy array inplace?

Thanks

Comment: The question 'is numpy better than other statistical packages...' is not really appropriate for SO. It's too vague: there are too many packages to compare to. It sounds like what you're looking for is help optimizing your code. What you have is very unoptimized. Consider rewriting your question to ask for suggestions on how to optimize your code. In particular, your use of `np.insert` is very slow because numpy has to create a new array each iteration.

Comment: Is there a missing `for` loop in your example code?

Answer (score 5):

It is never good to dynamically fill a numpy array, it involves resizing and copying.

The rolling median is not trivial as it seems.
[This blog article](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/tag/running-median/) talks about different implementations such as [Skip list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list).

EDIT: It seems you use pandas. In pandas an implementation using skip lists and skipping NaN in already implemented. Have a look [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.rolling_median.html).

A recipe for its implementation in pure python can also be found [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576930/).

Comment: Thanks, but won't it create numpy array everytime we add new element to the list and call np.median(list)?

Comment: I don't understand, you need to compute the median each time you read a line in the file ?

Comment: yes, since its rolling median. I need to read line by line, count unique words per line and find the rolling median.

Ex: line 1 - words - 5, line 2 - words 7, line 3 - words 10

Medians will be 5, (5+7)/2, 7

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing it like this. Assuming you've loaded a text file into `file`, you could create the list `a` as:

```
a = []
for line in file:
    a.append(num_unique_words(line))
```

Where I've assumed you have a function `num_unique_words` that calculates the number of unique words in a string.

Now convert it to an array:

```
a = np.array(a)
```

Now call `np.median` on [views](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) into the array (note that the views are created by [slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) the array:

```
median = np.empty_like(a)
for idx in xrange(len(a)):
    median[idx] = np.median(a[:idx])
```

Comment: Of course, numpy does perform an entire sort operation every time you call `np.median` here, rather than simply inserting the most recently added value into the sort. For this reason, @Kikohs answer provides links to methods that will certainly be faster.

Comment: Nice. This solution works if the entire contents of the file (number of unique words) can be loaded into memory.

But how to modify this solution to adapt to big datsets which can't be fit into the memory?

Comment: 200000 entries is not that many; it's only a couple megabytes or so. right? Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right @farenorth, I'm just trying to see whether this approach can be scaled to very large dataset

Comment: It seems to me that if your file is *that long*, you've got other problems. In particular, you'll want to implement the kind of fast 'running median' that @Kikohs suggests.